# Count mysql statement not returning correct value in java

Tags: java, mysql

I am getting a value of 9 from a count statement, but when I tried it in the localhost I am getting 18. Help me pls I'm stuck here thank you so much

Here is my code

```
private int getgoods;
String query="Select count(item_id) as 'total' from item_tb";
PreparedStatement pst =conn.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

while(rs.next())
{
         getgoods=rs.getInt("total");
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, getgoods); 
// supposedly to be 18 but im getting 9
```

[image: from mysql]

[image: from java , Im using eclipse]

Comment: Please could you crop your screenshots so that you don't have such a huge amount of whitespace?

Comment: Two things to check: (1) Are you absolutely sure you are connected to the same database? Not to a dev/production/staging/backup database? (2) Are you sure that between running these two tests, the data has not been changed in the table? Like rows being removed or rows that had their item_id changed to null?

Comment: @STEPHEN YAO, you are absolutely right. no need to modify code. check twice into another code which are not publish here. because you code perfectly sounds good.

Comment: You are making a mistake by mingling database and UI code together this way.  It's not too early to learn about interface-based design and layering an app properly.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. God bless always!

Answer (score 0):

Use `*` instead of `item_id` in the query like this,

```
String query="Select count(*) as 'total' from item_tb";
```

and use `if(rs.next())` instead of `while` loop.

Comment: there is no problem with `while`.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select count(*) as 'total' from item_tb");
rs.next();
int count = rs.getInt(1);
```

or

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select count(1) as 'total' from item_tb");
rs.next();
int count = rs.getInt(1);
```

Comment: He is running the same query in test and in myAdmin tool. So changing query should not have any effect. By the way, count(item_id) is also correct. The different between * and item_id, is that null values will not be counted.